# angularjs ng-repeat and create two tr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im creating a toggable element. Im in need to create two tr`s for each ng-repeat.

i want the result below, when clicking the first tr, then it will show the second.

How can i create two tr-`s for each ng-repeat without making multiple tables?

```
// repeat start 
   <tr class="rowlink" ng-repeat="i in vm.something" ng-click="show other">
                    <td><div >some info here</div></td>
                    <td><div >info</div></td>

                    <td><div >something here  </div></td>
                    <td><div >49</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="my toggable element">
                    <td colspan="4>
                        <div>some info from the ng-repeat here too.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
// first repeat done
```

**EDIT:**
i could make ng-repeat in the tbody, but then i get multiple tbodys, and i dont want that neither :|

Comment: Add `ng-repeat` on `tbody`

Comment: then it would make multiple tbody`s ? i dont want that @Rajesh

Comment: see this use ng-repeat in tbody http://jsfiddle.net/RkCMr/4/

Comment: can you provide sample of your output?

Comment: Use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end: https://thinkster.io/egghead/ng-repeat-start

Answer (score 1):

Something Like this

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
      <td>am there</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>am there too</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGOJwWcmSwo2xmgEkdeM?p=preview)

Comment: will ng-repeat-end be executed every repeat? and will it have same info?

Comment: it repeats all DOM elements between the starting element and ending element

Comment: can you provide a example? will ng-repeat-end have same information in item as ng-repeat start?

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML5 parent, like `tbody`, and use the ng-repeat over it:

```
<tbody class="rowlink" ng-repeat="i in vm.something" ng-click="show other">
   <tr>
       <td>some info here</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>some other info here</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

This way, you'll end with two tr for each iteration of ng-repeat.

### Edit

OP has asked to **not use** multiple tbody, so this isn't the answer he wanted. Nevertheless, this should be useful anyway to someone who has not those needings.

Comment: will that create multiple tbody`s?

Comment: @maria definitely it would be.. though it will be valid HTML

Comment: is it possible to create it without any exstra tbody`s? :)

Comment: It will, but it's legal in HTML5

Comment: Sure you can, just look at @M Balajivaishnav answer. by my opinion, it's far less intuitive.

Comment: @Luxor001 why you felt that its **far less intuitive?**

Comment: I find ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end to be unhandy: they rapresent a same iteration, but with different hierarchies.
In complex structures, i can easily get lost *where* the ng-repeat-start and end are. For me, a single parent that represent the iteration is more obivious.
It's all a matter of personal preference, though. Anyway, a single parent sometimes can't be used: using ng-repeat-start etc. in that case is the only solution.

Comment: @maria please refer the updated answer, sorry for the late reply was little busy with the work